# Get result using condition not works properly (C#)

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-core

I trying to get data from datatabase and assign it to list

Here is 2 conditions. 1 - I have only categoryId and 2 - I have category and subcategoryId

I wrote code like this

```
public async Task<List<TimelineItemDto>> GetFilteredClasses(int? categoryId, int? subcategoryId)
    {
        List<TimelineItemDto> filteredClasses;
        if (categoryId != null)
        {
            filteredClasses = await _context.Events
                .Where(x => x.CategoryId == categoryId && x.EventType == EntityType.Class)
                .ProjectTo<TimelineItemDto>()
                .ToListAsync();
        }

        if (categoryId != null && subcategoryId != null)
        {
            filteredClasses = await _context.Events
                .Where(x => x.CategoryId == categoryId && x.SubcategoryId == subcategoryId &&
                            x.EventType == EntityType.Class)
                .ProjectTo<TimelineItemDto>()
                .ToListAsync();
        }

        else
        {
            filteredClasses = await _context.Events.Where(x =>
                    x.EventType == EntityType.Class).ProjectTo<TimelineItemDto>()
                .ToListAsync();
        }

        return filteredClasses;
    }
```

but at first `if` I got this [image]

A second `if` and at `else` all okay and it's executed and filling list

How I can solve this?

Comment: Because you have a logical error. When `categoryId != null`, you will execute the first `if` block but then you will always execute either the following `if` or its associated `else` replacing whatever `filteredClasses` was assigned in the first `if`

Answer (score 1):

You should update the condition flow as below:

```
if (categoryId != null && subcategoryId != null)
{
    ...
}
else if (categoryId != null)
{
    ...
}
else
{
   ...
}
```

With above, the `filteredClasses` will not be overridden by last else condition. Your current code first evaluate `if` and then `if` & `else`. Both are different code blocks and last `else` is always getting executed.

Answer (score 1):

Well I would do something like below :

```
public async Task<List<TimelineItemDto>> GetFilteredClasses(int? categoryId, int? subcategoryId)
{
       var  filteredClasses = _context.Events.Where(x => x.EventType == EntityType.Class);
        if (categoryId != null)
        {
            filteredClasses = filteredClasses.
                .Where(x => x.CategoryId == categoryId);                
        }

        if (categoryId != null && subcategoryId != null)
        {
            filteredClasses = filteredClasses.Where(x =>  x.SubcategoryId == subcategoryId );              
        }      

        return await filteredClasses.ProjectTo<TimelineItemDto>()
                .ToListAsync();;
}
```

This way you will avoid materializing multiple queries.